# usermod -g doesn't apply permissions right away?

Tags: permissions, groups

I've noticed that when I add myself to a new group with `usermod newgroup -g wayne` I will have the group listed when I say `groups`, but if I were to do something such as

```
sudo mkidr /usr/local/grouptest
sudo chown root:newgroup /usr/local/grouptest
cd /usr/local/grouptest
touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch `test.txt': Permission denied
```

I get permission denied. When I'm connected across a ssh session, I have to re-connect and then the permissions are in effect for that directory. Is there a way to get around that? Especially since using GNU screen, I would have to kill and re-create all my windows which would be incredibly pesky.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`usermod -g` edits `/etc/group`, but `initgroups()` is only called by `/bin/login`.  That said, `newgrp` should work to switch to the new group, at the price of starting an extra shell.

Comment: That worked perfectly - don't have to restart my screen session, thanks!